# Android Studio - HAXM Install Error - AMD Processor

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I believe this is my first question - as such I apologize if I'm making mistakes or if this is posted incorrectly.

I am attempting to run *Android Studio* on *Windows 8.1*.
Android Studio works but I was unable to run my first test app due to an error with HAXM not being installed.

**Error in Android Studio when 'Run' is clicked:**

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! 
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. 
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

[image: AndroidStudioEmulatorErrorPNG]


Through the SDK Manager I 'installed' HAXM.

I understand that this only means HAXM is downloaded and still needs to be installed. HAXM files were placed into the 'extras' folder within the 'Android' 'sdk' folder. I then attempted to run the *intelhaxm-android.exe* executable. Initially I had to enter BIOS and enable Virtualization as it was defaulted to 'disabled'. I enabled the virtualization, rebooted twice and attempted to run the haxm installer again.
Now I am receiving a different error.

**Error from HAXM Installer:**

*This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.
Pleaser refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.*

[image: HAXMInstallerError]


From everything that I can find this computer is capable of supporting Virtualization (I am running Windows 8.1 with an AMD processor). Also, as I understand, an Intel vs AMD processor shouldn't make a difference for HAXM to operate??
I downloaded Crystal CPUID to help troubleshoot but, unfortunately, I don't even know how to read the results.

I'm at a complete loss here. I searched far and wide before posting. ANY help is appreciated.

[image: 3rd image]

Comment: Downloading Genymotion worked and I can now run the emulator. However, I still am unable to install HAXM. So this answer is more of a workaround. BUT, the problem is happily resolved so no worries :)

Comment: downloading the `Genymotion` is not way for solving this problem . if you can solved install `HAXM`  ,update your question .

Comment: haxm is *only* intel.  you shouldn't need to install it for amd.   i found that turing on windows virtualization and disabling hyperv works in the latest 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Intel Virtualization Technology through your Bios

Comment: Virtualization was definitely enabled through BIOS. I have checked and double-checked. It is still enabled...

Comment: I tried to like but I dont have enough reputation for it to show...