# (AMD) Android Studio Emulator keeps showing "x86 HAXM missing" error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, amd-processor

**I FOUND A FIX:**

**When creating a Virtual Device in AVD in the Image Section (where you select which android version you want to use) click on others and select one where it says arm64v8 or ami. This will fix the error message below and start the Emulator!**

---

Since Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 its possible to run the Android Emulator on AMD CPUs

I've downloaded Android Studio 3.3 and I activated Hyper-V in Windows Features.

I couldn't find Windows HyperVisor in Windows Features though. SVM is enabled (bios)

Whenever I run the Emulator the message:

`Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!`
[image: errorMessage]
When I try to install `Intel x86 Emulator Accelator (HAXM Installer)` from the Android SDK Manager then I get the following error (log file):

```
=== Logging started: 24.10.2018  22:29:57 ===
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. 
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

=== Logging stopped: 24.10.2018  22:29:57 ===
```

I have no idea why it isn't working, I followed every step from the [Android Dev Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html) & [stackoverflow replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466618/android-studio-haxm-install-error-amd-processor).

**Android SDK-Builds-Tools**: 28.0.3 | **OS**: Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit 1709 16299.665

**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (stock not oc) | **Mainboard:** MSi B350 PC Mate

---

Comment: Which processor do you use? I have not found a list of supported CPUs, only "Ryzen recommended"...

Comment: As stated in the question (maybe I updated it too late) CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (stock not oc)

Comment: Your solution to compile in ami means, that you will run software emulation, not CPU-supported hardware virtualization.
And software emulation is very slow.